# Wordpress is showing blank lines instead of images

Tags: images

[image]
[image]
I have just installed wordpress and it is not showing images/themes. I have tried wordpress on another device completely and it still shows this , please help.

UPDATE :

i have added a additional image which is shows the render output of images through a plugin Debugthis. (which is empty for all the themes which i try)

Comment: because you haven't upload any images yet. for example,edit "Hello World" post and add feature image then update post then visit site. you will see your attached image.

Comment: The default images of the theme should still upload , right? but they aren't uploading..

Comment: did you check in **wp-admin > media** ? is there any images which you have uploaded?

Comment: Yes i am definitely able to add images to the media library and upload them sucessfully. However i still want the default images of the theme to upload..

Answer (score 0):

This theme simply looks like that.
You can try another one.
Maybe, you'll like this post
https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-a-wordpress-theme/

Comment: I have tried other themes and the problem persists.